# my ckeditor is not loading the toolbar

Tags: ckeditor

I tried to install ckeditor in php but no result :S.

i have uploaded ckeditor file into the root of the site and i have a editor.html file where i have this code:

```
<html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

```
<form method="post">
    <p>
        My Editor:<br />
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">&lt;p&gt;Initial value.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

when i open the page it doesnt show the toolbar except a simple textarea.

Does any of you knows what I am actually missing here?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Check the location of `/ckeditor/`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was your case, but in case it helps anyone else in the future...

I was adding CKEditor to my project and the toolbar wasn't showing for me either. I could tell the javascript file was loaded (and css files). There were no javascript errors either.

Eventually I narrowed it down to a conflict between a jquery plugin (jquery.stylish-select) and CKEditor. When I removed the plugin, the toolbar showed up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {width: 1050, height: 500,  uiColor: '#e1e1e1'});
```

that means, you change the size....

So, can be, that it is better to use this CODE